# Preferences not emitted on first run

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have built a Firefox addon with the SDK. I'm using the simple-prefs module to store 2 user preferences. The issue is that the preferences are not emitted for the first run of the script. This is the main.js code:

```js
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var data = require("self").data;
var prefSet = require("simple-prefs");

pageMod.PageMod({

include: ["http://www.google.*","https://www.google.*"],
contentScriptWhen: 'end',
contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.7.1.min.js"),data.url("trackingdetector.js")],
onAttach: function(worker)
{
    // set preference variables
    var trackPref = prefSet.prefs.trackPref;
    var submitPref = prefSet.prefs.submitPref;

    worker.port.emit('get-prefs', [ trackPref, submitPref ]); // emit initial prefs

    function onPrefChange(prefName) {
        worker.port.emit('prefchange', [prefName, prefSet.prefs[prefName]]); // emit pref changes
    }
    prefSet.on("trackPref", onPrefChange);
    prefSet.on("submitPref", onPrefChange);
}
});
```

Then I use this code in the content script to catch the preferences:

```js
var trackPref;
var submitPref;

// get preference values here   
self.port.on("get-prefs", function(data) {
trackPref = data[0];
submitPref = data[1];
});

// get preference changes here
self.port.on("prefchange", function(data) {
    prefChange = data[0];
    prefValue = data[1];
    if (prefChange == "trackPref") {
        trackPref = data[1];
    }
    else if (prefChange == "submitPref") {
        submitPref = data[1];
    }
});
```

Works fine, expect on the first run, the values of `submitPref` and `trackPref` is always `undefined`. How do I make sure the script gets the initial values?

Answer (score 1):

Why should the prefs have a value different from `undefined` before you assigned anything to them? Simply initialize them at the beginning of your `main.js`:

```js
// Initialize prefs if necessary
if (typeof prefSet.prefs.trackPref == "undefined")
  prefSet.prefs.trackPref = false;
if (typeof prefSet.prefs.submitPref == "undefined")
  prefSet.prefs.submitPref = false;
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. The preferences are both booleans, so shouldn't those values be set from addon's options menu?

Comment: @JonathanBeeston: Ok, adjusted the example to use booleans. Sure, these prefs should be set from the options menu - but the extension needs to set *some* initial value for them, otherwise they will just be `undefined` until the user chooses some value. That's what this example does, it sets the default value if the user didn't choose anything yet.

Comment: I think I've been asking the wrong question here. The fact is that the prefs are defined in `main.js` (and have initial values given them in `package.json`). The problem is they are not emitted soon enough to the content script (even when I initialize them in `main.js`, as you suggest). I guess this is what is meant when it's described as 'asynchronous'!  That's why the first time the content script runs it sees the preferences as undefined, whereas subsequent runs it has them.

Thanks for your help Wladimir on this question, and other related answers that helped me get this far!